# How can I simulate a 'down' website?

Tags: web-services, http, web-applications, httpwebrequest

I am writing some failover code so that if my desktop app cannot connect to its website, it can instead try a backup website.

However, I cannot seem to figure out how to simulate a test if a website is 'down' or not. If I try an obvoiusly incorrect url such as "http://www.mybadsite.badTLD" , my ISP provider sends me to a default catch page.

Whereas when a site is truly down and you cannot connect to it, you get the browser message saying it cannot connect. This is what I need to emulate.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Edit your [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29#Location_in_the_file_system) to redefine the host you're trying to connect to.  You can do 127.0.0.2 (Or anything unreachable).

You can also do a test with 0.0.0.0 - that returns a different error (Invalid IP).  There may be some benefit to testing for that too.

Your ISP is redirecting for a DNS lookup failure, but anything resolved by your hosts file short-circuits that.

Answer (score 10):

In order to test how your scripts deal with different responses I'd rather use a special server that generates different HTTP codes. One of them is [httpstat.us](http://httpstat.us/)

In your case, the correct http status code is 503 (Service Unavailable).

> The 503 status code indicates that the server is currently unable to handle the request due to a temporary overload or scheduled maintenance

which will likely be alleviated after some delay.

For more information on http status codes I suggest reading [This IETS Documentation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6)

Answer (score 5):

```
http://localhost
```

Assuming you do not have a server running locally...

Comment: I actually used your answer, since it was easiest. I apologize though, I accepted the other as the 'proper' answer, since "localhost" is usually just an entry in the HOSTS file.  =)

Answer (score 5):

Stumbling upon this on 2020, I found this:

https://www.mocky.io/

https://httpstat.us/

Answer (score 1):

If you have a server that runs PHP, you could use the header() function to send headers for HTTP error codes back to your application.
`header("HTTP/1.0 404: Not Found", true, 404);`
or
`header("HTTP/1.0 403: Forbidden", true, 403);`
or
`header("HTTP/1.0 500: Internal Server Error", true, 500);`

These are some examples. Many server languages have methods for passing headers to the browser. Check this out for more error codes:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: Although these messages are the result of a successful connection, it is worthwhile to test for these situations too.

Comment: They are various other states of 'down' outside of the server not existing. :D

Answer (score 0):

I used this web service as follows:

```
curl -v http://httpstat.us/<http status code>
```

For example:

```
curl -v http://httpstat.us/503
```

The result is:

```
> GET /503 HTTP/1.1
> Host: httpstat.us
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
...
```